# How to get Google Authenticator QR code?

Tags: java, authentication, google-authentication

I'm trying to generate login info for my company OpenVPN server. It uses Google-Authenticator and I need to fetch the image to the client.

The problem is; the only way it authenticates is the default option(all yes). Like this:

```
tester@VirtualBox:~$ google-authenticator 

Do you want authentication tokens to be time-based (y/n) y
https://www.google.com/link // qrcode link
[QRCode image here, can't redirect to file]                                                               

Your new secret key is: xxx
Your verification code is xxx
Your emergency scratch codes are:
  xxx
  xxx
  xxx
  xxx
  xxx

Do you want me to update your "/home/tester/.google_authenticator" file (y/n) y

Do you want to disallow multiple uses of the same authentication
token? This restricts you to one login about every 30s, but it increases
your chances to notice or even prevent man-in-the-middle attacks (y/n) y

By default, tokens are good for 30 seconds and in order to compensate for
possible time-skew between the client and the server, we allow an extra
token before and after the current time. If you experience problems with poor
time synchronization, you can increase the window from its default
size of 1:30min to about 4min. Do you want to do so (y/n) y

If the computer that you are logging into isn't hardened against brute-force
login attempts, you can enable rate-limiting for the authentication module.
By default, this limits attackers to no more than 3 login attempts every 30s.
Do you want to enable rate-limiting (y/n) y
```

I try to set the flags; then redirect it to a file, grab the image URL but it doesn't match the default (authenticates fail):

```
google-authenticator -t -d -f -r 3 -R 30 -W > ~/test.txt
```

So the problem is:

- If I use the first way (run command and input yes all) it can authenticate but I don't know how to grab the QR code? Redirect it to a text file, it just hang for the input.
- If I use the second way; it doesn't authenticate (I think it doesn't match default option).

How to solve this? I use java, btw.

Comment: Is it a webapp?

Comment: @MauricePerry No; it isn't. It just a small tool written in Java.

Comment: Why are you fetching the image then? wouldn't it by easier to generate it? offline?

Comment: Oh, I mean fetch the generated image. BTW, my friend suggests me use `yes y | google-authenticator` and it quite satisfying me :D Thank you for your interest :)

Comment: OK. we're using ZXing for that https://github.com/zxing/zxing no connection needed.